# Is ANTLR the right approach for something like this?

Tags: java, antlr

So, I'm really stuck and starting to think its just not the right approach.
Consider this string: "[APPLE|ORANGE] PEAR"
The logic here *should* be 
"IF APPLE is in string, get me its color ELSE IF ORANGE is in string, get me its color ELSE return empty string. And now always return PEAR color".

I was able to get a [Hello World](http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2011/01/antlr-tutorial-hello-antlr/) working just fine.
1. I'm struggling with getting ANTLR to understand the conditional logic in my string.
2. I'm struggling with getting ANTLR to invoke getColor() per identifier.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated. I'm running on fumes at the moment.

```
grammar Test;

@header {
  package org.mytest.Test;
}

@members {
    private String answer = "";

    private void getColor(String fruit)
    {
        //Use java reflection to get Fruit class and invoke method getColor()
        answer = fruit.color;
    }

}

 @lexer::header {
  package org.mytest.Test;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

row returns [List<String> list]
@init {list = new ArrayList<String>();}
  :  a=value {list.add($a.val);} (WS b=value {list.add($b.val);})* (EOF)
  ;

conditionalString    returns [String color]:
                (
                a=IDENTIFIER (WS IDENTIFIER)* {getColor($a.text); } 
                )
                {$color=answer;};

//Get the text string for the matched identifier?
value returns [String val]  :  IDENTIFIER {val = $IDENTIFIER.text;}  ;


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

IDENTIFIER  :   ('A'..'Z')+;


WS : ( '\t' | ' ')+     { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

The ideal usage is below. The "context" argument would be some resource handle.
I would manually edit the Constructor to pass the context so ANTL knows how to handle each token.

```
TestLexer lex = new TestLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("[APPLE|ORANGE] PEAR"));
CommonTokenStream tok = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
TestParser par = new TestParser(context,tok);
System.out.println(par.conditionalString());
```

Comment: Although this is not what you really asked for, but have you considered using Parboiled (https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a grammar that I think is close to what you're asking for. It only handles cases exactly as you specified: `[id|id|id]` is a simple conditional and any `id` outside of a conditional is evaluated as-is.

#### Fruit.g

```
grammar Fruit;

@parser::members { 

    private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    private java.util.HashMap<String, String> colors = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();

    public void addColor(String fruit, String color){
        colors.put(fruit, color);
    }

    private void printColor(String fruit){
        if (colors.containsKey(fruit)){
            output.append(colors.get(fruit));
            output.append(" ");
        } else { 
            output.append("(no color for ").append(fruit).append(")");
        }
    }

    private void printColor(Token id){
        printColor(id.getText());
    }

    private void evaluateCondition(java.util.List<Token> tokens){
        for (Token token : tokens){
            String fruit = token.getText();
            if (colors.containsKey(fruit)){
                printColor(fruit);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

conditionalString returns [String result]
@after { result = output.toString();}
            : expr
            ;

expr        : cond_expr+
            ;

cond_expr   : ID
            {printColor($ID);}
            | LSQB values+=ID (OR values+=ID)* RSQB
            {evaluateCondition($values);}
            ;

OR          : '|';
LSQB        : '[';
RSQB        : ']';
ID          : ('A'..'Z')+;
WS          : ('\t'|' ')+ {skip();};
```

Here is the test class. Method `addColor` on the parser exists to simplify testing. For example, if fruit "ORANGE" is colored "orange" and the input string is "ORANGE ORANGE", then the output is expected to be "orange orange".

#### FruitTest.java

```
public class FruitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream("[APPLE|ORANGE] PEAR");
        FruitLexer lexer = new FruitLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        FruitParser parser = new FruitParser(tokens);

        parser.addColor("APPLE", "red");
        parser.addColor("ORANGE", "orange");
        parser.addColor("PEAR", "yellow");

        String result = parser.conditionalString();

        if (lexer.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0 || parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0){
            throw new Exception("Syntax errors encountered!");
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

#### Test Case 1: Lots of fruit

- APPLE = red
- ORANGE = orange
- PEAR = yellow

Input:  `[APPLE|ORANGE] PEAR`
Output: `red yellow`

#### Test Case 2: Plenty of fruit

- ORANGE = orange
- PEAR = yellow

Input:  `[APPLE|ORANGE] PEAR`
Output: `orange yellow`

#### Test Case 3: Low on fruit

- PEAR = yellow

Input:  `[APPLE|ORANGE] PEAR`
Output: `yellow`

#### Test Case 4: Hunger strike (no fruit colors defined)

Input:  `[APPLE|ORANGE] PEAR`
Output: `(no color for PEAR)`

Since `PEAR` is not part of a conditional, it's expected to be defined.

Comment: I didn't go into detail about how the grammar works since I'm not sure what would be most useful for you at this point. Let me know if you have questions about any of this and I'll do my best to answer.